# How to remove intermediate folders containing only one folder each?

Tags: bash, file, shell, recursion, mv

I had been playing around with mv, and now I have a situation.
Earlier, say
Folder1 had file1,2,3.

Now Folder1 has Folder2 which has Folder3 which has Folder4 which contains file1,2,3.

I am trying to write a bash script such that it identifies intermediate folders containing only 1 directory and moves all its contents up one level, ultimately giving back only Folder1->file1,2,3, and rest folders deleted.

I tried to write something like below, but I am :

1.unable to distinguish between file and folder

2.unable to find the file/directory name stored inside current folder

3.Not sure how to do recursively.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Directory Name?"
read dir_name

no_files=`ls -A| wc -l`

if [ $no_file==1 ] && [ itisaDirectory()];
then `mv folder_name/* dir_name`
fi
```

Comment: Hint: `[ -d "$file" ]` will be true if `$file` is a directory.

Comment: Your code contains syntax errors already; see http://shellcheck.net/ for fixes. (It fails to warn about the wacky backticks around the `mv` command, though.)

Answer (score 0):

When you do not care for error messages and want to move all files in subdirs to the current dir and remove the remaining empty dir, do something like

```
find . -type f -exec mv {} "${dir_name}" \; 2>/dev/null
rm -r */
```

You ask for something else, only move files where an intermediate directory is unique. That is the case if exactly one subdir has that dir as a parent. The parent of a dir can be found with `dirname`.
When a dir has one subdir, only one subdir will have it as a parent. You can list all dirs, look for the parent and select the unique paths.

```
find . -type d  -exec dirname {} \; | sort | uniq -u | while read dir; do
   echo "${dir} has exactly one subdir"
done
```

The problem is that the dir can have files as well. We try to improve the above solution:

```
find . -exec dirname {} \; | sort | uniq -u | while read dir; do
   echo "${dir} has exactly one subdir or one file"
done
```

You can test the content of the dir with `if [ -d "${dir}/*" ]` but I do not need to know:

```
find . -exec dirname {} \; | sort | uniq -u | while read dir; do
   echo "${dir} has exactly one subdir or one file"
   find "${dir}"/*/ -type f -exec mv {} "${dir_name}" \; 2>/dev/null
done
```

The path ${dir}/*/ will only exist when ${dir} has a subdirectory in it, and will move the files beneath. When $dir only has one file, the find command will find nothing.